# How Can I make my header disappear and reappear by clicking a button and also have the button change my page background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My HTML:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Public Vision</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="backbone" href="backbone.css">
    <link rel="alternative stylesheet" type="text/css" title="alt" href="alt.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body class="style2">
    <div id="header" class="style2"><div id="header2" class="style2">Public Vision</div></div>
    <iframe width="640" height="400" 
     src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLX9_I-EOJPdFuOjcI2zkmTck55homHEBE" 
     frameborder="2" allowfullscreen></iframe>

    <input id="showHideContainer" type="image" src="off.jpeg " height="3%" width="2%" alt="On" onclick="toggle()";>

    <script>
    function toggle(){
$('body').toggleClass('style2');
    }
    </script>
    <script>
    document.getElementById('showHideContainer').onclick = function() {
    divTest = document.getElementById('header');
    if (divTest.style.display === "none") {
    divTest.style.display = 'block';
    }
    else {
    divTest.style.display = "none";
     }
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

My CSS:

```
     #header {height: 15%; width: 100%; background-color: white; z-index: 2; position: fixed; right:0; top:0;


    box-shadow: 0 4px 4px -2px #232323;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 4px 4px -2px #232323;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 4px -2px #232323;
   }   

   #header2{height: 15%; width: 100%; position: fixed; color:grey; opacity:  0.6; text-align: center; z-index: 4; font-size: 30px; margin-top: 2.5%;    background-color:clear;}
   iframe {display:block; margin: 0 auto; margin-top: 17%;}


   body{
   background-color:grey; z-index:3;
      }
   body.style2{
    background-color:white; z-index:3;
     }
```

Currently, the image I have  now, when clicked makes the header disappear.
any ideas on how I can make the image make the header disappear and the background change color? Really hitting a brick wall here. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it's not working is that right now you're overwriting the `onclick` event in your JavaScript. You start out with an `onclick` on your `input` element, then when you set the `onclick` again in the JavaScript, it overwrites your original `onclick` that calls `toggle()`.

One way to fix this would be to use [event listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick), which support binding multiple functions to `onclick`, but in your case it will be easier to just add the `toggleClass` into the `onclick` you define in your JS, and remove the one you have in your `input` tag. Here is an example that toggles both header visibility and background color, by using a single `onclick` function for each:

**Working Live Demo:**

```js
document.getElementById('showHideContainer').onclick = function () {
    divTest = document.getElementById('header');
    if (divTest.style.display === "none") {
        divTest.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        divTest.style.display = "none";
    }
    $('body').toggleClass('style2');
};
```

```css
body {
    background-color:grey;
    z-index:3;
}
body.style2 {
    background-color:white;
    z-index:3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header" class="style2">
    <div id="header2" class="style2">Public Vision</div>
</div>
<input id="showHideContainer" type="image" src="http://i.imgur.com/5LGqY2p.jpg?1" height="100" width="100" alt="On" ;>
```

JSFiddle Version: https://jsfiddle.net/66cn8L1b/1/

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly!

Comment: @AustinJones Glad it worked for you! Please don't forget to mark it as accepted by clicking the gray checkmark to the left of the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Will do! on a side not do you know if i could make the transition from one color to another slower, almost like the background is dimming or a light turning on?

Comment: @AustinJones You can use the transition CSS rule for that: `body{transition: background-color 1s; ... }`

Comment: Thanks again! It's greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$('body').toggleClass('newClass');` inside your same click event for hiding the header. Here's fiddle demo http://jsfiddle.net/ff2o7gmy/1/.